# clang compiler produces different object files from same sources

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gcc, clang

I have a simple hello world objective-c lib:

hello.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "hello.h"

void sayHello()
{
    #ifdef FRENCH
    NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello World!\n";
    #else
    NSString *helloWorld = @"Bonjour Monde!\n";
    #endif
    NSFileHandle *stdout = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput];
    NSData *strData = [helloWorld dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [stdout writeData: strData];
}
```

the hello.h file looks like this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]);
int sum(int a, int b);
void sayHello();
```

This compiles just fine on osx and linux using clang and gcc.

Now my question:

When running a clean compile against hello.m multiple times with clang on ubuntu the generated hello.o can differ. This seems not related to a timestamp, because even after a second or more, the generated .o file can have the same checksum. From my naive point of view, this seems like a complete random/unpredicatable behaviour.

I ran the compilation with the `-S`to inspect the generated assembler code. The assembler code also differs (as expected). The diff file of comparing the assembler code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/uY1LERGX

From a first look it just looks like the sorting is different in the assembler code.

This does not happen when compiling it with gcc.

Is there a way to tell clang to generate exactly the same .o file like gcc does?

```
clang --version: 
Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
```

Comment: Well, they're different compilers, so you shouldn't expect the *exact* same output. But why does the .o file *need* to be the same? If you're just generating an executable it shouldn't matter... sometimes there are small inconsistencies in the compilation process.

Comment: I the object files are different when I compile them with exactly the same clang compiler (and exactly the same parameters). I don't expect that the .o file created by clang and gcc look exactly the same

Comment: @ReneGroeschke, do you build with parallel make (`make -j`) or with multithreaded tools? Some differences may come from these. Also, sometimes compiler may use `random()` inside, so gcc has `-frandom-seed=###` to fix the random seek. The feature is called "Reproducible Builds". I can't find info about Reproducible builds with llvm. And the lase (rarest) source of instability is ASLR, combined with usage of object addresses as keys of hashes (maps) and iterating over the hashes (it may reorder symbols like with .quads in your diffs)

Comment: @osgx no i don't use parallel tools or multithreading at this stage. I can reproduce this by triggering plain clang from the commandline. thanks for the tip about the `-frandom-seed`. i read something about that already but havn't tested it in detail. setting `-frandom-seed=0`doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Rene Groeschke, -frandom-seed was option of GCC not of clang. Try to disable ASLR in ubuntu by [`echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization)

Comment: thanks osgx. This did indeed the trick. But I'm feeling uncomfortable to disable it in the long term.

Comment: Rene Groeschke, Did disabling of ASLR help you?

Answer (score 5):

The feature when compiler always produce the same code is called Reproducible Builds or deterministic compilation.

One of possible sources of compiler's output instability is ASLR ([Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). Sometimes compiler, or some libraries used by it, may read object address and use them, for example as keys of hashes or maps; or when sorting objects according to their addresses. When compiler is iterating over the hash, it will read objects in the order that depends on addresses of objects, and ASLR will place objects in different orders. The effect of such may looks like your reordered symbols (.quads in [your diffs](http://pastebin.com/uY1LERGX))

You can disable Linux ASLR globally with [echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization). Local way of disabling ASLR in Linux is

```
 setarch `uname -m` -R /bin/bash`
```

man page of `setarch` says: [-R, "--addr-no-randomize" Disables randomization of the virtual address space (turns on ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE).](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setarch)

For OS X 10.6 there is `DYLD_NO_PIE` environment variable (check `man dyld`, possible usage in bash `export DYLD_NO_PIE=1`); in 10.7 and newer there is `--no_pie` build flag to be used in building the LLVM itself or by setting `_POSIX_SPAWN_DISABLE_ASLR` which should be used in `posix_spawnattr_setflags` before starting the llvm; or by using in 10.7+ the script http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py with `--no-pie` option to clear PIE flag from llvm binaries ([thanks to asan people](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/issues/detail?id=29)).

---

There were some errors in clang and llvm which prevents/prevented them to be completely deterministic, for example:

- [[cfe-dev] clang: not deterministic anymore?](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2009-November/006965.html) - Nov 3 2009, indeterminism was detected on code from [LLVM bug 5355](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5355). Author says that [indeterminism was present only with -g option enabled](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2009-November/006986.html)
- [[LLVMdev] Deterministic code generation and llvm::Iterators](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-January/028878.html) (2010)
- [[llvm-commits] Fix some TableGen non-deterministic behavior.](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20120910/150732.html) (Sep 2012)
- [r196520 - Fix non-deterministic behavior.](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20131202/197746.html) - SLPVectorizer was fixed into deterministic only at Dec 5, 2013 (replaced SmallSet with VectorSet)
- [190793 - TableGen: give asm match classes deterministic order.](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130916/188077.html) "TableGen was sorting the entries in some of its internal data structures by pointer." -  Sep 16, 2013
- [LLVM bug 14901](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14901) is the case when order of compiler warnings was Non-deterministic (Jan 2013).

The patch from 14901 contains comments about non-deterministic iterating over llvm::DenseMap:

```
-  typedef llvm::DenseMap<const VarDecl *, std::pair<UsesVec*, bool> > UsesMap;
+  typedef std::pair<UsesVec*, bool> MappedType;
+  // Prefer using MapVector to DenseMap, so that iteration order will be
+  // the same as insertion order. This is needed to obtain a deterministic
+  // order of diagnostics when calling flushDiagnostics().
+  typedef llvm::MapVector<const VarDecl *, MappedType> UsesMap;
...
-    // FIXME: This iteration order, and thus the resulting diagnostic order,
-    //        is nondeterministic.
```

Documentation of LLVM says that there are non-deterministic and deterministic variants of several internal containers, like `Map` vs `MapVector`: [trunk/docs/ProgrammersManual.rst](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/docs/ProgrammersManual.rst?revision=194720&view=markup&pathrev=194720):

```
1164    The difference between SetVector and other sets is that the order of iteration
1165    is guaranteed to match the order of insertion into the SetVector.  This property
1166    is really important for things like sets of pointers.  Because pointer values
1167    are non-deterministic (e.g. vary across runs of the program on different
1168    machines), iterating over the pointers in the set will not be in a well-defined
1169    order.
1170    
1171    The drawback of SetVector is that it requires twice as much space as a normal
1172    set and has the sum of constant factors from the set-like container and the
1173    sequential container that it uses.  Use it **only** if you need to iterate over
1174    the elements in a deterministic order. 

...

1277    StringMap iteratation order, however, is not guaranteed to be deterministic, so
1278    any uses which require that should instead use a std::map.
...

1364    ``MapVector<KeyT,ValueT>`` provides a subset of the DenseMap interface.  The
1365    main difference is that the iteration order is guaranteed to be the insertion
1366    order, making it an easy (but somewhat expensive) solution for non-deterministic
1367    iteration over maps of pointers.
```

It is possible that some authors of LLVM thought that in their code there was no need to save determinism in iteration order. For example, there are comments in ARMTargetStreamer about usage of `MapVector` for `ConstantPools` ([ARMTargetStreamer.cpp - class AssemblerConstantPools](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/llvm/llvm/lib/Target/ARM/MCTargetDesc/ARMTargetStreamer.cpp#46)). But how can we sure that all usages of non-deterministic containers like DenseMap will not affect output of compiler? There are tens loops iterating over DenseMap: ["DenseMap.*const_iterator" regex in codesearch.debian.net](http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=DenseMap.*const_iterator)

Your version of LLVM and clang (3.0, from **2011**-11-30) is clearly too old to have all determinism enhances from 2012 and 2013 years (some are listed in my answer). You should update your LLVM and Clang, then recheck your program for deterministic compilation, then locate non-determinism in shorter and easier to reproduce examples (e.g. save bc - bitcode - from middle stages), then you can post a bug in LLVM bugzilla.

Comment: thanks for this detailed explanation. The clang version is shipped with ubuntu 12.04.3. I'll double check with my newer installations. cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Try the `-S` option for clang and gcc during compiling your source. This will generate a `.s` file in which you can see the assembler code this could give you an idea what the differences on a lower level. Maybe you will realise the output will be the same and your problem shifts from the compiler further down to the linker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. turns out the .s files also differ. I've linked the diff file here: http://pastebin.com/uY1LERGX and updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You should report this as a bug; a compiler certainly *should* be deterministic.

Your guess about the sort order is quite probably correct, in my experience. Most likely the compiler makes an arbitrary decision when two items compare equal (according to whatever measure is significant; they don't have to be actually the same), and that can vary depending on environmental factors, somehow. I've seen this before, in GCC, in which the same compiler compiled for different host OS produced different results; in that case it turned out that the Windows qsort function operated slightly differently to the Linux (glibc) implementation.

That said, it could be something else; compilers aren't supposed to make random decisions, but there plenty of opportunities for arbitrary decisions that might turn out to be unstable, somehow (address space randomization, perhaps?)