# How best to compare two compiled binaries?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I recently discovered an excellent visual studio extension which finds unnecessary #include statements in projects and removes them.  I work on some gnarly legacy code and it's stripped a huge amount away.  The only problem is that I can't be sure that it hasn't altered the build in some subtle way.  It occurs to me that a project may still build but a #define somewhere could have been altered.

Anyway, it's occurred to me that I could be sure that no important changes have been made by checking the binaries.  I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how best to do this?  The obvious problem is that a small amount of meta data in the binaries will change because of compiler metadata about build times, etc.

Ideas so far:

1. Disassemble all the binaries and compare the disassembly with diff.  (Although this wont't cover the data sections I guess).
2. Use some kind of binary diff program that's aware of PE headers.

Any ideas?  And anyone know of a tool which understands PE headers as I describe?

Comment: *"And anyone know of a good binary diff program like I describe?"* At almost 20k rep you should understand that you're walking dangerously close to off-topic-ness here. :)

Comment: Yeh, I guess that's true.  But this is the kind of question only fellow programmers will likely know the answer to.

Comment: *no important changes have been made by checking the binaries*   Given that you've modified *gnarly legacy code and it's stripped a huge amount away*, you've made significant changes.  What kind of testing do you do?  Because you have to redo **ALL** of it now.

Comment: @Andrew I'm doing this early in our project schedual so it will get regression.  This is tech debt as far as I'm concerned.  Also if the binaries can be shown to be functionally identical I'm happy at this stage of the project.

Comment: Some compilers tend to be non deterministic. Even the same input code is not guaranteed to generate the same output. Checking semantic equality of binaries is a "hard" problem. You need to rely on your test cases to be sure that nothing has broken.

Comment: most likely your binaries will be different due to difference in debug info and possible elimination of some unused code. So, no  comparison can really be reliable in this case. Your best bet is thorough testing of the new code as was suggested above. For the comparison of macro expansions, it might be easier to run the cpp and compare related parts of expanded texts.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Really?  I'd never heard that before.  I'm even more interested in trying the disassembler idea now...

Comment: @Benj compilers use sets, maps and many other data structures. Behavior of many of these do not provide ordering guarantees. I cannot provide you an example of same source generating different binaries, but I strongly believe it happens.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You may well be right in which case this approach won't work.  I'm going to try disassembling so I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Benj you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765444/clang-compiler-produces-different-object-files-from-same-sources) discussion. The OP in that question has posted an example where they get a different output. They have also provided an assembly dump.

Comment: You don't need to disassemble the binary, you can generate assembly using the `-S` option in gcc and clang. I remember cl has `/FA` flag. Be careful about the line numbers and other debug information though. You can strip it off from the output to retain only the instructions.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That's a good idea, I should have considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PE header is always at the same place and ranges only up to 512 Bytes (exactly).
so just truncate off the first 512 bytes and compare the results then.

I pipe them through xxd to convert the files to hex, then I diff the resulting text files (any text diff program will work, but you need git commandline to get xxd).

```
xxd -p -c 4 < Truncatedfile1.exe > output.diff1
```

or

```
tail -n -512 < File1.exe | xxd -p -c 4 > output1.hex
tail -n -512 < File2.exe | xxd -p -c 4 > output2.hex
git diff --no-index --color output1.hex output2.hex
```

Note that I made the lines just 4 bytes long to have a chance that alignment (especially occurring in data sections) shuffles me the lines back in shape when an odd number of bytes is inserted in between. If you are extra lucky, your code is also DWORD-aligned, then it works with your code just as well.

Comment: Thanks!  So it sounds like this is a method that's worked for you?  Some in the comments are saying that compilers are too non-deterministic for this idea to work.

Comment: Well, I do edit binaries with automated stuff on binary scale, and as a Software tester, I have some experience in checking for differences. I just thought about how the data sections could be diffed and remembered that it is usually dword-aligned, so I thought that xxd with 4 bytes per line would be a good Idea also for re-compiled programs.